# Nifi, Run database update before insert

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a record that I want to use the `PutDatabaseRecord` processor on, however before I insert the record, I need to update the table.

essentially: generate data -> run custom sql -> `PutDatabaseRecord`

I know I could probably do this with the `ExecuteSQL` processor (using the pre and post fields), however then I think i would have to copy all of the content into attributes so I could access them using `EL` in the processor config.

Is there a way to do this without a custom processor?

Comment: Could you please give us more context as what are you trying to update. From your question I understand that you want to persist the record into the DB.

Comment: I have a table that contains two relevant columns, "id" and "isCurrent". The new record that I want to add needs to be the only record in the table with the same id that is marked as current. So the first update marks all the old ids as not current, and the insert adds the new current record @DataWrangler

Comment: So I presume that the `ID` field is stored as an attribute, you can then use the `ExecuteSQL` processor and have a `UPDATE` command written in the properties by substituting the ID field with the attribute. Then issue the `PutDatabaseRecord`. You just need to get the `ID` value as an attribute, which can be fetched using processors based on the type of the flowfile

Comment: the issue with that is after the `ExecuteSQL` the content of the flowfile is changed from the data I want to save to the result of the sql executed. I just found wait/notify but I dont want to setup a distributed cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @mattyb pointed out is the right way to go, so your flow would be something like this

[image: Sample Flow]

Source Fetch (example Generate Flowfile) -> UpdateAttribute (Fetch the ID field as attribute) -> PutSQL (`SQL Statement`) -> PutDatabaseRecord

[image: PutSQL]

- In the above example I issued a SQL statement `INSERT INTO public.so_test (id, "name", iscurrent) VALUES(1, 'John', 'True');` in Generate Flowfile
- Hardcoded the value `1` in UpdateAttribute, your case it needs to be fetched from the flowfile
- PutSQL has the statement `UPDATE public.so_test set iscurrent='False' WHERE id = ${id};` where id is the value replaced from the attribute
- Finally `PutDatabaseRecord` the flowfile that comes out after PutSQL is the same as its input

Answer (score 0):

Use `PutSQL` instead of `ExecuteSQL`. When you specify the `SQL Statement` property it is used instead of the FlowFile content, and it doesn't replace the content after it executes the statement.